# MySQL function works in localhost but does not exist when uploaded to server

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code for MySQL function

```
mysql_query("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS Review_Text;");
mysql_query("
CREATE FUNCTION Review_Text(rID INT)
RETURNS TEXT
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE Ans TEXT;
SET Ans = (SELECT `Text` FROM `data` WHERE `ID` = rID);
RETURN Ans;
END");
```

Which works beautifully on localhost. However, when I uploaded my files to online server the following error happens

> FUNCTION mydatabase.Review_Text does not exist

Does anyone know why this happens and can it be fixed?

Comment: why do you have the _deprecated_ mysql functions anyway? and what errors are you getting?

Comment: What is a deprecated mysql function? I have a limited knowledge in MySQL.

Comment: deprecated again!, try `mysql_query('CREATE ... ') or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @user3741635 Kindly read `mysqli` or `PDO` with _prepared statements_ to know why/how they help. the _deprecated_ mysql functions will no longer be available

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari, so should I rewrite my entire code from MySQL to mysqli?

Comment: Can you check if the function itself is created? Maybe you don't have enough rights on the online server to create functions. What is the output of @rray suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you should switch from `mysql_` functions/driver to the `mysqli` or `PDO` driver. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php Specifically `It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development, as it has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and will be removed in the future.`.

Comment: @sanderbee, this error comes up `Access denied for user '1022634'@'localhost' to database '1022634'`

Comment: @user3741635, then that's the problem. Check your login data, contact your hosting provider. You have no permissions to the database.